# css override on a class

Tags: css

Here is the [page](http://produits-lemieux.com/odeurs.html) I have a problem with

on each image (little square) i apply the class `<div class="odeurbox">` that should be 67 pixel wide...the result is a box 480 pixel wide

Why is the style is superseded by something else.... obviously, there is something i dont understand from the CSS cascading ..

any light ?

p.s. i know you dont care, but it look good in dreamweaver... sob !

Comment: ah ah !.... found.... missing } in my css... stupid me !, thanks

Comment: haha I think we found it about the same time! I just started deleting everything in the file until it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a } bracket for the class:

```
.textplusbold {
    color: #002B4E;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Line 198 of the css file. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well your `.odeurbox` class's `width: 67px` value should override any parent style width's. Have you got the width set on the odeurbox class?

Comment: yes, obviousely !..   .odeurbox {
 float: left;
 width: 67px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

Comment: Well this is a bit of a pickle isn't it!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a style for the `.odeurbox` style. Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.odeurbox { width: 67px; }
```

Comment: Sorry - missed the 2 in the stylesheet name. It wasn't anywhere in base.css or lemieux.css... ;)